# Bootstrap CSS How To: Create a ContentBox with a Title Bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to know how to make a "ContentBox" with a title bar similar to this login box:

https://github.com/login?return_to=%2Fjshint%2Fjshint%2Farchives%2Fmaster

Is there a simple way using bootstrap css or do I just need to come up with my own way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The page you linked does not show the login for anyone who is already logged into GitHub, so you may want to be a little more specific next time or post a screenshot.

That being said, I assume you just want the blue gradient header over a box of some kind.  It's very simple to do, but there are no components of that nature built in to Bootstrap.

If you want to see what GitHub (or any other site) has done to create the effect you're looking, many tools are available to *inspect* the source. Here is a screenshot of Chrome's built in debugger (F12).

[image]

Edit: That image is being zoomed out a bit too much, here's a closer look.
[image]